# CSS variable in background image

Tags: css

I am defining css variable like

```
<style type="text/css">
      @variables {
        static:{{STATIC_ROOT_PATH}};
      }
    </style>
```

I want to use this variable while framing image path. 
Is it possible something like

```
background: transparent url('var(static)/images/button_bg.png')
```

This code is not working for me.

How can I frame image path based on static value ?

Comment: what is the value of {STATIC_ROOT_PATH}

Comment: It will be generated on fly 
example 
//stackoverflow.com/staic

Comment: Note that this would be a potential vulnerability, you could stehel css variable content if it were allowed to embed css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that variables are an implemented part of CSS3 at this time. A quick google search returns only articles debating the usefulness of said variables.

I saw earlier someone posted about this extension: http://sass-lang.com/, which allows variables and mix-ins, you may want to look into that?

Someone comment and correct me if I'm wrong.